# IE 8 doesn't open certain website, firefox does

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

OS: Windows XP SP3. When I try to open the website `brokerkf.ru` in IE8, it says, that it can't find the server. While it opens google.com and many other websites.

Firefox and Chrome open `brokerkf.ru` without any problems. nslookup  shows the website IP address correctly in the command prompt.

This domain is not in /etc/hosts file.

What could be the issue? I am puzzled.

Comment: IE8 is pretty old school at this point. The website owners/programmers may have decided that older browser version support is not worth it.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I know. But at least it should have connected to the site, while it doesn't.

Comment: On the gripping hand, [Firefox is dropping extended security support of XP this month](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/end-support-windows-xp-and-vista)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Checking the SSLLabs TLS protocol support (found at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=brokerkf.ru), this site only supports TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2. The most recent version of TLS that IE8 supports is TLS 1.0. So effectively, IE8 and the site cannot agree on a version of TLS to use, and as such your browser cannot connect to the site.

Note that this is also the case for every other user agent which gets that type of failure: all those products only support TLS 1.0 as the most recent version, while the server doesn't support anything older than 1.1.

Comment: And as TLS 1.0 is broken, more and more sites are turning it off. You may be able to turn on TLS 1.1 or 1.2 deep in the browser options somewhere. Doesn't mean IE 8 will work on sites that haven't tested for it, though.

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. It's unlikely to be a case of "turning it on somewhere in the settings". The SSL/TLS component for Internet Explorer is actually part of the OS, and there are many features which Microsoft never backported to Windows XP (by the time TLS 1.1 came out, XP was 5 years old, and Vista was nearly ready for release). This table on Wikipedia suggests that TLS versions past 1.0 are among them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Web_browsers

Comment: I had just vaguely remembered that some old versions of IE had TLS 1.1/1.2 as options, they were just off by default as they were too new and experimental at that time. Maybe IE 8 wasn't one of them. I didn't have a copy of XP anywhere handy to check.

Comment: The reason a server would be configured this way is because, a client can attack the server in such a way, where it downgrades to TLS 1.0 which of course is not considered safe.  *I use the word "attack", the context of performing any action, that has hostile intentions.*  If Windows XP has the ability to support TLS 1.1/1.2 it would have been added years ago, this will not happen, so you should move away from Windows XP if you have to use a browser on it.  This limitation of being unable to use TLS 1.2 extends to ALL browsers by the way.

Comment: @Ramhound Only those browsers that depend on those OS provided libraries. I believe Firefox and Chrome contain the own SSL libraries. Not that either browser supports Windows XP anymore for new versions (the current Firefox LTS is last version that will support it, and will soon be unsupported too).

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. Because IE relies on the OS for SSL/TLS, it's not so much "_does IE8 support TLS1.1+?_" as "_does the OS?_". It's _possible_ (can't remember for certain) that IE8 on a later OS (e.g. Windows 7, that _does_ support TLS1.1+) could use TLS1.1+ and would be able to connect.

Comment: @TripeHound As the SSL Labs scan says, IE8 through 10 on W7 also fail to connect.

Comment: @Nzall OK. Slightly surprised by IE10 on Windows 7 failing... although IIRC (which might not be the case) Windows 7 with IE10 didn't have the options to use TLS1.1/1.2 turned on by default, so -- depending how they do the _simulation_ -- it _might_ show as a fail, although it _might_ be possible to configure things to work.

Comment: Even Windows Vista only has TLS1.0, but Windows 7 has TLS1.2, and IE11 connects when I try.

Comment: @Neil IIRC IE11 on Windows 7 turns on the "try TLS1.1/1.2" options by default, whereas I've a feeling they were _off_ by default with IE10 and Windows 7 (but could be turned on).

Comment: I have reason to believe that IE8 ***on XP*** doesn't even support TLS 1.0. This is according to SSLlabs. SSLlabs also tells me that IE8/XP does not support *Foward Secrecy* or *Server Name Identification*. None of these are issues on IE 8/Win 7 or even on IE 7/Vista.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Octopus: where do you see that at SSLLabs? I have one old XPSP3/IE8 system for testing and it certainly DOES do 1.0. It doesn't do SNI, and only half-does FS: it does DHE-DSS but not DHE-RSA, and essentially nobody on the public net has a valid DSA cert although I saw some intranets use that back when, plus it only handles DHE-1024 correctly not 2048 (or more) as now required.

Answer (score 42):

It seems the site is not supporting older useragents, which can only use outdated TLS, see here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=brokerkf.ru 
The result shows, that for a lot of older browser versions the connection is closed by the server. So this is not an issue with the pc you are using, it's done by the webserver itself.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - as @Nzall says, they're not *actively* blocking anyone, let alone by user agent (which necessarily requires a connection be established and a request made first). They're just not going out of their way to support an older (insecure) protocol. So... yes, it *is* an issue with the client: the client is too old!

Comment: to say the answer is "incorrect" is also incorrect :-)  (...unless being pedantic -- which is perfectly fine, if measured). Paraphrasing, yet likely still flawed, perhaps this is better phrasing: "Older user-agents are _effectively_ blocked, since they do not support newer technology, and their attempts to connect to the server fail."

Comment: @michael "_ 
to say the answer is "incorrect" is also incorrect :-) is incorrect_" (albeit pedantically). The site is blocking by SSL/TLS protocol, and some _systems_ (in this case XP) don't support the required level (TLS1.1/1.2). While a "user agent" could provide its own implementation of the required protocols, many/most (including IE) don't and rely on the OS's implementation.

Comment: I don' think it's pedantic. The answer as given implies that they are intentionally blocking specific browser versions. They are not. They simply lack the older version of a protocol, and thus any browser without the newer versions can't connect to them. It really is an issue with the browser.

Comment: Correlation does not imply causation. You gotta identify who's being blocked in a big ol' table, so you might as well use "user-agent". Correct, the server isn't using user-agent, hence, _"effectively"_ . (Horse now properly dead.)

Comment: @michael this answer is plain, simple, 100% inaccurate *in addition* to being misleading.

Comment: Calm down people :) I have edited the answer for correctness